# Mutliple CSV files through AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new at AWS and looking for example code. My problem is the following. I loaded a zipped file in my S3 bucket which contains several CSV files with different column names.

I would like with the use of my AWS Lambda handler (in Python) is to:

1. Unzip each file
2. Turn each file to panda dataframe
3. Iterate over each for data cleaning
4. Then concat merge them into a final data frame.

On my local system I did all this with no problem. The problem is that it did not work on Lambda.

If any examples where they have seen at list step one and two done. That would be helpful. I have seen examples online for one CSV file, but not for a zipped file containing multiple CSVs in it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please expand on what didn't work. Error message and code throws it.

Comment: What problem are you getting, when it's not working on lambda?  There are few possibilities, lambda is limited in running time and memory so keep that in mind.  Another is that you need to package up dependencies such as panda along with your code to use it.